# Converting a normal OOP SQLi statement to a Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following normal User class statement that I'm trying to convert to a prepared statement.

```
public function didReceiveRequest($user_from) {
    $user_to = $this->user['username'];
    $check_request_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to='$user_to' AND user_from='$user_from'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_request_query) > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm new to prepared statements and have been doing pretty well throughout the User class, but am still having trouble with a few.  Being new, I don't follow the logic as well, so please go easy.  Here is what I have so far:

```
public function didReceiveRequest($user_from){
   $user_to = $this->user['username'];
   $check_request = $this->con->stmt_init();
   $check_request->prepare('SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to=? AND user_from=?');

   $check_request->bind_param('ss', $user_to, $user_from);
   $check_request->execute();

   $result = check_request->get_result();
   $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

   $check_request->free_result();
   $check_request->close();

   if($data > 0){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;}
}
```

So a couple things abt this:  1)I know there is probably a better and more efficient way to do this.  And 2) Will what I have return the same result as what was there (with normal statement) previously.  I don't want to mix up calls from my dependent pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would use MySqli prepared statements for your case example.

```
public function didReceiveRequest($user_from) {

$query = "SELECT * 
FROM friend_requests 
WHERE user_to = ? AND user_from = ?";

$user_to = $this->user['username'];

$stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param(ss, $user_to, $user_from); //set your bindings
$stmt->execute();
//$results = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);//Use if you want to see results.

if($stmt->num_rows !== 0) {
return TRUE;
}else{
  return FALSE;
  }

}
```

Here is a really good link to read that teaches you how to use prepared statements with MySqli.  I would bookmark this link and refer to it often.  [MySqli prepared statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Using prepared statements does not affect how you receive the results from you query.

Comment: I didn't get a good result with this.  I did it like below and it worked.

Comment: So what was not working, what was it not doing, any errors?

Comment: I'm past this now so can't remember the exact error, but it pointed directly `didReceiveRequest`.

Comment: Ok, no problem.  But in the future please post the errors in your questions. It will help others figure out your issues.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The difference I see in what was provided as an answer is `$result = $stmt->get_result();`  Again being new to prepared statements I'm not 100% that this is the reason above code throws an error, but this code works.

```
 public function didReceiveRequest($user_from) {
    $user_to = $this->user['username'];
    $stmt = $this->con->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare('SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to=? AND user_from=?');

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user_to, $user_from);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $qty = $result->num_rows;

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

    if($qty > 0) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```